# GigaPixel panorama in HTML 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to build a gigapixel panorama in HTML 5 and Javascript. Similar to this one - http://visualise.com/panoramas/ipad-and-iphone-html5-gigapixel-panoramas

Any ideas of places to start or any APIs to look at?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, firebug is your friend with this. It turns out that the site uses 'panopress' which luckily turns out to be free - http://www.panopress.org/

Unluckily, it also turns out to be a Wordpress plugin - you could however have a look at the associated javascript and work it out from there  . ..

Comment: Thanks. I found this tool - http://krpano.com/html5multires/ it's a paid product, seems to do what I need.